# pick element with condition and sum by row in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
data<-fread(
     V0  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
 1: 116 116 116 116 102  96  NA 106 116  NA 144
 2: 122 122 114 114 114 114  NA 121 111  98 108
 3: 118  88  78  78  77  72  96  NA  95  NA  NA
 4: 118 118  77  NA  86 139 127  NA 103  93  84
 5: 150 150 154 154 121 121 114 111  NA  NA  NA
 6:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 141
 7: 174 174 174 125 118 117 116 139 116 102 104
 8: 183 183 183 175 175 176  NA 139 123 140 141
 9: 134 140 106 174 162 162 169 140 127 112  NA
10: 178 178 178  NA  NA 116  95  95 125 115 103)
```

I try to sum elements by row with condition(<90) like this

```
     V0  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 sum
 1: 116 116 116 116 102  96  NA 106 116  NA 144  0
 2: 122 122 114 114 114 114  NA 121 111  98 108  0
 3: 118  88  78  78  77  72  96  NA  95  NA  NA  88+78+78+77+72
 4: 118 118  77  NA  86 139 127  NA 103  93  84  77+86+84
 5: 150 150 154 154 121 121 114 111  NA  NA  NA  0 
 6:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 141  0
 7: 174 174 174 125 118 117 116 139 116 102 104  0 
 8: 183 183 183 175 175 176  NA 139 123 140 141  0
 9: 134 140 106 174 162 162 169 140 127 112  NA  0
10: 178 178 178  NA  NA 116  95  95 125 115 103  0
```

raw data is large over 10000 row, so I don't prefer for loop 
please use data.table

Comment: You can't know the condition in advance unless you sum the rows first. Technically you could sum each row until you meet the condition but that will be even slower. In general, data.table/data.frames don't work so well with rows, so you basically have two options: 1- `melt` the data and sum by group (look for "wide to long r" in Google), or convert your data.table to a matrix and sum by rows, e.g. `data[, Sum := rowSums(.SD) < 90]` (`Reduce` won't work here because of `NA`s).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way in base R:

```
data$sum <- rowSums(data * (data < 90), na.rm = TRUE)
```

In `data.table`, you can do:

```
data[ , sum := rowSums(data * (data < 90), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

---

```
     V0  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 sum
 1: 116 116 116 116 102  96  NA 106 116  NA 144   0
 2: 122 122 114 114 114 114  NA 121 111  98 108   0
 3: 118  88  78  78  77  72  96  NA  95  NA  NA 393
 4: 118 118  77  NA  86 139 127  NA 103  93  84 247
 5: 150 150 154 154 121 121 114 111  NA  NA  NA   0
 6:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 141   0
 7: 174 174 174 125 118 117 116 139 116 102 104   0
 8: 183 183 183 175 175 176  NA 139 123 140 141   0
 9: 134 140 106 174 162 162 169 140 127 112  NA   0
10: 178 178 178  NA  NA 116  95  95 125 115 103   0
```

Comment: or `mysum <- function(x) sum(x[x<90], na.rm=TRUE);
data[, mys:=apply(data, 1, mysum)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x=c(1,100,5),y=c(200,5,15), z = c(1,2,NA))
df["sum"] <- df %>% 
               apply(2, function(x) ifelse(x < 90,x,0)) %>% 
               rowSums(na.rm = TRUE)
df
```